# Including i18n translations in jade.renderFile() WITHOUT express

Tags: internationalization, pug, i18next

I have an app that I've been doing translations with using the old i18n `__(' ')` syntax in my jade files, but now I am moving my emailing functions outside of my express controllers.

Now doing them using jade.renderFile(), it's not recognizing `__(' ')` anymore. Is there a way to include i18n in calls to renderFile?

Jade/Pug I suppose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply!
But if you still care about this issue, try the following code:

`app.post('/render', (req, res) => {
    var options.__ = res.__;//forward`__`function
    jade.renderFile('code.jade', options, function(err, html){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(html);//completed html contain i18n value
    });`